# Next.js - Lock screen in landscape mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, screen-orientation

I am working on a canvas animation project using Next.js. I want it to open in **landscape** orientation (in case of mobile phones), so I have added the following code in `index.tsx`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary");

    // rest of the code
}, []);
```

This is not working. The project does not open in landscape orientation when I run it on my phone. Also, I can change the orientation by tilting my phone.

[image: NotSupportedError message]

Also in case of firefox, I am getting the above error message.

[image: NotSupportedError message mobile]

I am getting the above error message in firefox when I run the project my phone. I do not get any error message on Chrome (desktop or mobile).

Comment: The Screen Orientation API is still an experimental technology, not yet supported by all major browsers: https://caniuse.com/screen-orientation.